# must have thought of vs must have been thinking of someone else

Tags: perfect-continuous

Alice - Who does this car belong to?

Tim - To that neighbour with a red hat

Alice - I thought he didn't like cars

Tim - You must **have been thinking of** someone else

Alice - You're right. I was **thinking of** someone else.

A native said to me that we need the continuous aspect in these cases (instead of *must have thought of* and *I though of*)

If you can please consider my viewpoint:
My conceptualisation was that in this conversation the image of the neighbour (the false one) pops in the mind of Alice and she doesn't dwell on it. So this image pops up like a flash and so Alice uses "though of" to refer to this single event, which is why there's no place for the continuous aspect.
So I think the continuous construction would work if for some reason we would want to stress that this mixing up of the people has been taking place over an extended period
Does this make sense?

Comment: It's an idiom, "I was thinking of something/someone else". I can't find references right now, but that's the way English speakers always say it. "I thought of something else" has a different meaning - it means "I had a new idea".

Comment: You must have been thinking of someone else. Or: You must be thinking of someone else. Definitely a continuous is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alice - Who does this car belong to?

Tim - To that neighbor with a red hat

Alice - I thought he didn't like cars

Tim - You **must have been thinking of someone else.**

Alice - You're right. **I was thinking of someone else.**
OR

Alice - Who does this car belong to?

Tim - To that neighbor with a red hat

Alice - I thought he didn't like cars

Tim - You **must be thinking of** someone else.

Alice - You're right. **I am thinking of someone else**.

Most definitely, a continuous form would be used: present or past.

The more likely usage is present continuous. But thought is fleeting, so the past is OK, too.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, is 'must' replaceable by 'had to' here? So 'you had to be thinking about someone else'.

Comment: @ASDASDASDASD Yes, basically, it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to put that in the past simple, it implies *a single thought.*

- *"Alice - I thought he didn't like cars."*
- *"Tim - You must have thought of someone else."*

-- Tim suggests someone came into your mind momentarily, or you remembered someone.

Putting it in the past continuous implies, in this case, *a belief.*

- *"Alice - I thought he didn't like cars."*
- *"Tim - You must have been thinking of someone else."*

-- Tim is suggesting that you believed something about someone.

Because this is following the statement:

- *"I thought he didn't like cars."*

... it is contextually referencing this *belief* about what he liked or did not like.  If past simple is used again after this, as in "You must have thought of someone else," either it does not apply to a belief, or it implies that you had since changed your mind about what he liked, and no longer believe now as you did then.  This is probably not what you mean to imply.  You likely still hold the same view about what he likes now as you did earlier--which is why you are asking about this in an incredulous tone, as if you cannot believe otherwise to what you had previously understood.

Comment: @Lambie I have attempted to explain why the simple past is not appropriate in this context, as you also appear to say in your comment above: _"Definitely a continuous is needed."_ My explanation of what it does to the meaning given the simple past is not to encourage its use but to point out that it conveys a different thought, one that is likely not intended.

Comment: @Lambie Whether or not present continuous or past continuous is used depends on the context of the entire conversation.  If this is narration of a prior conversation, past continuous is appropriate.  If this is a current, ongoing conversation, yes, present continuous should be used.  It wasn't clear to me in which context this conversation was framed.